# Authentication using random digits in the password

Tags: c#, java, authentication, encryption, passwords

This question is more of a design know how rather than a pure technical problem.

I am wondering what would be the best way to implement a authentication mechanism where users are asked to enter/select characters from specific positions in their whole password. ex. asking the user to enter/select the 3rd, 5th and 9th characters and then checking whether they have entered/selected the correct characters from their original password.

As far as I know, passwords are salted and encrypted using an irreversible algorithm before storing them. When a user enters his whole password, it is then salted again, encrypted and compared with the stored value. But in the above case where only certain characters are entered/selected how would one check against the whole password?

Below are the two (unsafe) ways I know to implement the above

- Breaking the original password into individual characters and then
  salting and encrypting them. Then comparing the user entered value
  against the specific character.
- Breaking the original password into predefined set of combinations like 2nd, 3rd & 7th characters together and then salting and
  encrypting them. Later comparing with the user entered value.

But I think with the above implementations it is easy to crack the password rather than cracking a password which is encrypted as a whole.

What would be the safest way of implementing this?

---

UPDATE:
Just found that this topic has been discussed in detail [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-do-some-sites-e-g-online-banks-only-ask-for-specific-characters-from-a-pa) and it mentions about using [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) and symmetric encryption.

Comment: Feels like awesome way to drive people insane/away from your app/site. Have you tried to do it yourself? (I mean how long it will take you to enter 8th character of your password - no writing it down, not typing)...

Comment: The safest/best way to implement it? To not. Something to think about: by asking for the 3/5/9 characters for a password, you're essentially reducing their password to three characters.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree, its not user friendly. But apparently most of the banking websites in the UK have adopted this mechanism and I am just curious to know how it works/implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Decomposing the password into different parts that a hacker can independently attack reduces the overall complexity of the password significantly.  Essentially you allow the hacker to play "20 questions" with the password: "Are the separate digits 500?  No, how about 750?"

Additionally, the vast majority of typical app users will find this task difficult, challenging and annoying.

I would not suggest doing this.

You are correct that the salted, *hashed* (not encrypted) password is typically stored.  If you are hashing rather than encrypting, you would need some mechanism to separately know what those particular digits of the password are.  You *should* be salting/hashing.  Several high-profile sites had many user accounts compromised because they used encryption, and the encryption key was found by hackers.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this you're lowering the entropy the password gives you.  Take for example an 8 character password.  Now lets assume that your password is chosen at random and we're trying to brute force it just by trying every combination.  The formula for this is (n+r-1!)/r!(n-1)!  meaning for 8 characters (r=8) (upper and lower case and numbers n=(26*2+10)) all your combinations would come out to **8361453670** different combinations.

Now lets say out of that you ask them to give you the 1st, 3rd and 6th characters you've effectively reduced the number to choose (r) to 3, because to brute force every combination I only need 3 characters.  The total number of combinations you have now is **41664**, which is a LOT easier to crack.  In fact this would take no time.

You should never reduce your entropy, in fact I recommend making passwords atleast 10 characters with letters numbers and symbols.

As to your question about "irreversable encryption,"  you're referring to hashing.  Passwords should be stored hashed and salted, and in fact they should use a slow hash like BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2.  But to be able to do what you're saying you're going to be required to encrypt the password with a reversable encryption.  This is a no-no because the key could get stolen in which case your passwords might as well be in plain text.

The best approach to storing passwords is to not store them (use open id or something else if you can so you don't have to take on the responsibility).  The second best approach to storing passwords is store them as if you're going to loose them.  Salted+Hashed with a very slow algorithm that will give you enough time to warn your users and give them enough time to change their passwords.

Answer (score -2):

Passwords are typically stored in an encrypted format.  It is encrypted with a particular salt.  The salt tells the encryption algorithm some initialization vectors.  This encryption is one way.  There is no way to decrypt it.

This way it is extremely difficult to build a rainbow table of passwords because you would need to do this with  every salt combination too.  See the following WIKI.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

The method you are proposing would severely degrade security that you would get from a good password.

Comment: -1 passwords typically *are not* stored in [encrypted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) form. Hashed, but not encrypted. (And your answer mostly repeats existing one...)